# Event data from Smart Contract parsing issue with go-ethereum

Tags: go, go-ethereum

I am unable to get the full data emitted from SC event by using `types.Log` channel. Is there any way so that I can have all the data from an event emitted?

The event I'm trying to parse:

```
PairCreated(address indexed,address indexed,address,uint)
```

My code:

```golang
for {
        select {
        case err := <-sub.Err():
            log.Fatal(err)
        case vLog := <-logs:
            fmt.Printf("Log Block Number: %d\n", vLog.BlockNumber)
            fmt.Printf("Log Index: %d\n", vLog.Index)

            event := make(map[string]interface{})
            err := contractAbi.UnpackIntoMap(event, "PairCreated", vLog.Data)
            if err != nil {
                log.Fatal(err)
            }
            fmt.Println(event)
        }
    }
```

I could only parse the last two arguments of the event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understood what was wrong here.
If an argument is declared as `indexed` that argument goes to `Topics` instead of `Data`. And there can be at most 3 topics. So, I tried to unpack the topics but failed. And succeeded with the following way:

```golang
token1 := common.HexToAddress(vLog.Topics[1].Hex())
token2 := common.HexToAddress(vLog.Topics[2].Hex())
```

And pair was in `Data`

So, the final code is:

```golang
for {
        select {
        case err := <-sub.Err():
            log.Fatal(err)
        case vLog := <-logs:
            fmt.Printf("Log Block Number: %d\n", vLog.BlockNumber)
            fmt.Printf("Log Index: %d\n", vLog.Index)

            event := make(map[string]interface{})
            err := contractAbi.UnpackIntoMap(event, "PairCreated", vLog.Data)
            if err != nil {
                log.Fatal(err)
            }
            fmt.Println(event)

            token1 := common.HexToAddress(vLog.Topics[1].Hex())
            token2 := common.HexToAddress(vLog.Topics[2].Hex())
        }
    }
```